# Hasura: Convert object array to number array

Tags: graphql, hasura

I have a query that looks like this:

```
    query ($email: String!) {
      users(where: {email: {_eq: $email}}, limit: 1) {
        id
        email
        name
        clients {
          id
        }
      }
    }
```

and when executed returns something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "name": "Billy",
        "clients": [
          {
            "id": 1
          },
          {
            "id": 2
          },
          {
            "id": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to modify the query and/or hasura so that the `clients` array is an array of numbers instead of an array of objects so it looks like this (`clients` is another table not a jsonb field)?

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "name": "Billy",
        "clients": [1, 2, 3]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: if it is a part of object/type (and can contain other fields) then of course not ... as returning only array of numbers doesn't return declared type for this prop ... you can extract/modify it after receiving

Comment: I assumed I would have to modify it after receiving it. I wasn't sure if there was a way to map it on hasura or not...

Comment: for single prop you can have f.e. some 'format' param on string type field to receive plain text or rendered/html ... and in theory you can define type as an array of some union type elements (int or Client) it could be possible to return it both ways conditionally (with resolver support of course)

Comment: I would do that in postgresql with ARRAY_AGG/JSONB_AGG. I'm not aware of possibilities to do that on graphql level.

Comment: Okay, Thanks everyone for the feedback. I will just create the array via javascript.